# K&R exercise 1-21

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

> Exercise 1-21. Write a program `entab` that replaces strings of blanks
> by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing.
> Use the same tab stops as for detab. When either a tab or a single
> blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given
> preference?

The code I wrote for the exercise:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAB 8

void entab(int space);

int main()
{
    int c, i;

    i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            ++i;

        else if (c == '\t')
            i = i + TAB;

        else
        {
            entab(i);
            i = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void entab(int space)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; space >= TAB; ++i)
        if (i == TAB)
        {
            putchar('\t');
            i = 0;
            space = space - TAB;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < space; ++i)
        putchar(' ');
}
```

But when I give it the input  "3 blank spaces + a tab + 5 blank spaces + j"  the output I get is longer than the input :

[image: The first line in the picture is the input and the second line is the output]

The first line in the picture is the input and the second line is the output

Update:

Rewrote the code based on one of the comments and one of the answers into this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAB 8

void entab(int space);

int main()
{
    int c, i, l;

    i = l = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++l;

        if (c == ' ')
            ++i;

        else if (c == '\t')
            i = i + TAB - (l%8);

        else
        {
            entab(i);
            i = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }

        if (c == '\n')
            l = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}


void entab(int space)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; space >= TAB; ++i)
        if (i == TAB)
        {
            putchar('\t');
            i = -1;
            space = space - TAB;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < space; ++i)
        putchar(' ');
}
```

but now the problem is that it's always one characters less than the input:
[image]

Comment: Look at this line:  `i = i + TAB;`  This adds `8` to `i` regardless of the value of `i`, which is obviously wrong.  A hard tab moves you to the next tab stop.  So the number of equivalent spaces is anywhere from `1` to `8`.  This code always uses `8`, which is a bug.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood how tab works

Comment: @ryyker The code I originally posted is still up there

Comment: I don’t get it, right there after the line “the code I wrote for the exercise:” at the begging of the post is my original code. The code I rewrote is further down at the end of the post. My original code is still up there

Comment: Before even opening your source code editor or IDE, you should make a plan, including example inputs and expected outputs. Only if you have that, consider to write code. -- Did you try to debug your program by single-stepping through it? With the expected output at hand, you should easily see where your program goes wrong. Follow the values in your variables.

Comment: Please edit the question so that the title is informative and sums your actual problem. Your current question title contains no useful information making the question and answer less useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't fix the code above so I rewrote it entirely and methinks it works if anyone's interested:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAB 8

int main()
{
    int i, c, l;

    i = l = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            ++i;
            if ((l%8 + i) == TAB)
            {
                putchar('\t');
                l = i = 0;
            }
        }
        

        else if (c == '\n')
        {
            putchar('\n');
            l = i = 0;
        }

        else if (c == '\t')
        {
            putchar('\t');
            l = i = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            ++l;

            while (i)
            {
                putchar(' ');
                --i;
                ++l;
            }

            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Would be better with documentation. The `'\n'` and `'\t'` cases are identical, so they can be combined to `else if (c == '\n' || c == '\t') { putchar(c); l = i = 0; }`. Could be updated so that `l` will not overflow even with absurdly long lines.

Comment: Retracted my "not quite right" answer. This is good. Two things: In the block handling SP, `if ((l%8 ` should be `if ((l%TAB `. And, to note that this will swallow ragged trailing SP's on a line while outputting trailing tabs... (ie: both "\t\n" and "\t     \n" output as "\t\n".  Otherwise, good!

Comment: One more thing (that is subject to "opinion"): With a _tabstop_ of 8, the string "1234567 abcd" will have that single SP converted to a tab. Some might say that this is inappropriate.

Answer (score -2):

The output you are seeing is longer than the input because the program is replacing each space with a tab and some spaces. You should modify the `entab` function to replace strings of blanks with a tab followed by the appropriate number of spaces.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define TAB 8

void entab(int space);

int main()
{
    int c, i, l;

    i = l = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        ++l;

        if (c == ' ')
            ++i;
        else
        {
            entab(i);
            i = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }

        if (c == '\n')
            l = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

void entab(int space)
{
    int i, num_tabs, num_spaces;

    if (space == 0)
        return;

    num_tabs = space / TAB;
    num_spaces = space % TAB;

    for (i = 0; i < num_tabs; ++i)
        putchar('\t');

    for (i = 0; i < num_spaces; ++i)
        putchar(' ');
}
```

Comment: @TomKarzes yes, you are correct apologies for the confusion. I have now corrected the code

Comment: The code in this answer is wrong. For a line of A, seven spaces, and B, it outputs A, seven spaces, and B, but the correct output is A, tab, and B.